# /.profile "Unexpected EOF while looking for matching `" '

Tags: bash, command-line

I am new to the terminal and have been working towards adding Grunt to my workflow. I am receiving this error in my Terminal and I don't see any missing " in my .profile file.

```
-bash: /Users/shawnwilliams/.profile: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: /Users/shawnwilliams/.profile: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Here is my .profile (Edited as I provided the wrong file.)

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin” # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using a non-ascii double-quote character after /usr/local/bin.  Try changing the double quotes to ascii.

Comment: @ShawnWilliams: I suspect that you wrote or modified that .profile file with a word processor that has a so-called [smart quotes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/smart_quotes) feature. So you need to disable that when editing scripts.

Comment: @ShawnWilliams: It might be a good idea to get an editor intended for programming use. Such editors have colour-coded syntax highlighting (usually for a wide variety of programing languages) that allows you to _instantly_ see typos like the one in your question. Programmers' text editors also have various other handy features, like bracket & brace matching, auto-completion, etc. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors

Comment: @2Ring: I'm using Sublime Text 3, but I did not see the inappropriate quotes highlighted. That is why I was having difficulty finding the error. It was more obvious in the browser than in the code editor.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your .profile, not .bash_profile, as indicated by the error message.
your .profile is sourced in the first line and then bash complains.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking at both files and pasted the wrong one. I edited the original post. I still don't see any missing quotes though.